# unexpected token ':'. expected a ')' or an... error when loading a react native app in android emulator

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-studio

when I am trying to run a react-native app in a andorid emulator , I am getting this error as in below image,[image: emulator image]

react version 17.0.2 / java version 8 / node version 16.13.1

can someone suggest a solution for this ?

Comment: Can you share the code that causes this error as a [mre], per [ask]?

Comment: @esqew there is no errors showing in my code. this appears only when im trying to run  app in emulator.

Comment: "*there [are] no errors... in my code*" It's pretty obvious that the emulator doesn't think so. Even so, we really cannot help you very much at all if you don't share the code that eventually compiles to what you're testing here.

Answer (score 0):

This likely means you have a missing ',' **comma** in an object definition. Could be in your styles or any where you create an object as so:

```
const object = {
  firstAttribute: 'firstValue',
  secondAttribute: 'secondValue',
  thirdAttribute: 'thirdValue',
  // etc...
}
```

Missing one of those comma would result in a similar error.